# $R^2$ correspondence for nonlinear time series

Tags: time-series, goodness-of-fit, nonlinear-regression, r-squared

Is there a statistical measure for nonlinear time series data that is comparable to $R^2$ value in linear regression (giving an idea of how well the fit is)?

The data is not monotonic, so I cannot use Spearman's $\rho$; and it's not linear, so Pearson's $\rho$ is not valid here either.

Data looks like below (It's mostly monotonic decline. But since there is a spikes in the 11th year, it's not strictly monotonic):

[image: mostly monotonic decline. But since there are multiple spikes, it's not strict monotonic]

Here is the fitted exponential curve (in blue) and the original data (in red)

[image]

Here is the qqplot: (Doesn't seem to be a good fit although it should be a good one because of the image above?)

[image]

Comment: You want to the know how good the "fit" is. But what are you fitting?

Comment: I'm trying to fit it to a decline curve that is exponential.

Comment: Just added some more information.

Comment: Those look like R plots. What function did you use to estimate the exponential curve? It almost produces some goodness-of-fit statistic unless you wrote it yourself.

Comment: I meant "almost certainly"

Comment: Yup the curve was bade based on experience functions. But I want to know how good the fit is. If it were linear, we can tell the goodness of fit based on R^2. But not sure if there is something similar to R^2 for a non-linear fitting?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "experience functions." Could you just post the R code you used to generate the plots? In any case, there isn't a *general* analogue of R^2 that I know of, but in my understanding there's no reason you can't just compute it anyway. It's just a function of MSE, which you could use instead if you're still unsure.

Comment: In addition, some of your comments are a little backwards. It's not a precondition of calculating Pearson (Spearman) correlation that patterns are linear (monotonic); rather it's the job of those measures to quantify how far patterns are linear (monotonic). Further, nothing stops you calculating correlation or its square between any set of observed values and the corresponding predictions and using that measure as a descriptive statistic.

Comment: what makes you think the QQ plot isn't linear?

Answer (score 1):

There is no standardized formula. One approach to derive an $R^2$ like score is to transform the test statistics in a likelihood ratio test, like how Negalkerke's $R^2$ is constructed in GLM models.

In your case, there may be a simpler approach. I guess the model you use is:

$$
y = e^{\beta' x + c}
$$

If that is the case, you can simply apply the log transform: $z = \log(y)$, and your model becomes linear:

$$
z = \beta' x + c
$$

You can compute the $R^2$ as in the classical linear models.

BTW, I guess your model is really "nonlinear regression" rather than "nonlinear time series". Usually "nonlinear time series" means models like GARCH, FARMA, and I guess those are not your case.

Comment: If the OP's data are observed over time and are in time order, it's reasonable to call the time-series, even if using only regression methods to fit a model. It's to be encouraged because it highlights likely kinds of deviation from model assumptions that would be obscured if the label 'time series' was avoided merely because classically time series methods were not presently being applied to the time series data.